# How to make php files by which MySQL, PHP, phpmyadmin, Apache, Python etc. details will show?

Tags: php

How can I make a php files which will show the details of PHP, Apahce, MySQL, phpMyAdmin, Python and Ubuntu system usage and information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP see http://php.net/phpinfo for examples. Basically put ...

```
<?php

// Show all information, defaults to INFO_ALL
phpinfo();

?>
```

in a file inside your document directory and name it phpinfo.html and you can access that file from your browser when apache is running.

> Apache

I would advice to use the apache module **[mod_status](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_status.html)**

> There is also mod_status built into Apache web server to get server
>   status from a web browser. With this module you can easily find out
>   how well your server is preforming. All reports are generated in a
>   html format. You can easily find out following type of information:
>
> ```
> Total number of worker serving requests
> Total number of of idle worker
> Find the status of each worker, the number of requests that worker has performed and the total number of bytes served by the worker
> Total number byte count served
> Other information such as CPU usage, number of requests per second,current hosts and requests being processed etc.
> ```

So this can be done by setting up apache. [Example](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/apache-server-status/).

Mysql has a command `mysqladmin -u root -p status` to show various settings but there is no modules for this to show that in a browser. The same goes for Python. Probably because of security concerns that this is not available.

If you need more things you need to elaborate on the "etc".